# Curly braces around a parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Looking at some Angular code:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: 'kendoGrid.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        public editDataItem: Product;
        public isNew: boolean;
        private editService: EditService;    

        public editHandler({dataItem}) { // What does wrapping a parameter in curly braces do?
            this.editDataItem = dataItem;
            this.isNew = false;
        }
    }
```

I could not find much result when I try to google curly braces / moustache with parameter in the context of Angular. What effect is achieved by wrapping a parameter in curly braces in Angular?

Thanks.

Comment: This is called deconstruction in JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's known as [*destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it works like so:

Say you have an object which contains a person's name and age:

```
const person = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 42
};
```

And you have a function which prints out the `age` of the object passed to it:

```
function printAge(obj) {
    console.log(obj.age);
}
```

This function uses the whole object - however, since we don't actually need the other properties of the object (only `age`) we can use destructuring to extract that property:

```
function printAge({ age }) {
    console.log(age);
}
```

This is ES6 shorthand for the following:

```
function printAge(obj) {
    var age = obj.age;
    console.log(age);
}
```

So, all that this function does:

```
public editHandler({ dataItem }) {
    this.editDataItem = dataItem;
    this.isNew = false;
}
```

Is this ES5:

```
public editHandler(item) {
    var dataItem = item.dataItem;
    this.editDataItem = dataItem;
    this.isNew = false;
}
```

Comment: In other words: Destructuring is a shorthand to access the key-value pair's value of a complex object via its key name?

Comment: Yes exactly @taylorswiftfan.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding an object like

```
const dataItem = {test: "test"};
```

and pass it to a function, in ES6 we can directly pass an object like the one below.

```
public editHandler({test: "test"}) { 
        this.editDataItem = test;
        this.isNew = false;
    }
```

curly braces are nothing but an object.

Comment: No, you're not passing anything, you're defining a function which will be passed an object.

Comment: Yes it is not necessarily defined, if it is defined outside. Anyways you got a better answer. Cheers!